# Error on a Sinatra's middleware

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, middleware

In my Sinatra app, I've created the following middleware to ensure the incoming request contains the parameter "token" in the query string

```
class CheckMandatoryParams
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call(env)
    # Get token from query string
    h = Hash[*env["QUERY_STRING"].split('&').map {|s| s.split('=')}.flatten]
    token = h["token"]

    # Do not authorize request unless both parameters are not null
    if token.nil? then
      Log.instance.error("CheckMandatoryParams - token not provided")
      [401, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain", "Content-Length" => body.length.to_s}, ["Unauthorized"]]
    else
      Log.instance.debug("CheckMandatoryParams - token provided")
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

In the case the params exists, the next app is calls and everything goes fine.
In the case the params is not in the query string, the response is not sent, I receive a huge html file indicating an error at the line ' [401, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain", "Content-Length" => body.length.to_s}, ["Unauthorized"]]' but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

This is working better like that :)

```
body = "Unauthorized"
[401, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain", "Content-Length" => body.length.to_s}, [body]]
```

I did not manage to retrieve the param with the following code though:

```
request = Rack::Request.new(env)
token = request.params["token"]
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see what error you're getting from the Rack::Request code. That's one way I've commonly seen to access params in Sinatra without having to parse the query string with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "body" variable may be undefined. One possible way to rewrite your code would be as follows:

```
class CheckMandatoryParams

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    token = request.params["token"]
    if token.nil?
      [401, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain", "Content-Length" => request.body.length.to_s}, ["Unauthorized"]]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed out the right thing. I updated the question.